# why does the get function in this situation return a key error, and what would be the best alternative method?

Tags: python

I have a list of dicts that, for example, contain the key "foo" and may or may not contain the key "bar", and I would like to obtain the value of "bar" in each dict. That value can be derived from "foo".

```
thing = {"bar": 2}

def no_bar(thing):
    return thing["foo"]

thing.get("bar", no_bar(thing))
```

Why does the get method run in this scenario, when thing already has the key "bar"?

A key error also occurs with the setdefault method.

I could keep the default value to None, then derive the value of "bar" if the returned value is None, but I don't know if this is the best solution.

Comment: Your question is not clear, what do you expect to happen and how is it different from the actual results? `thing` doesn't have `'foo'` in your example, `KeyError` is expected.

Comment: What's even the point of the function, why not `thing.get('bar, thing['foo'])`

Comment: There is no key `foo`, thus `thing["foo"]` when you call `no_bar(thing)` will raise `KeyError`. Note that default value is evaluated always, i.e. it is not evaluated only when key (first argument to `get()`) is missing if that is what you think.

Comment: The evaluation order is always the same. The arguments to a function are evaluated before being passed to the function. In other words, `no_bar(thing)` is called and its return value is passed as argument to `get`. That's how all Python evaluation works and `get` is no special case.

Comment: @mousetail I imagine the real `no_bar` applies some further transformation to derive the proper value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you get the error is - when you use `no_bar(thing)`, the python interpreter immediately runs the function (because you are calling the function).

To avoid this, you can try what you suggested in the question itself:

```
bar = thing.get("bar")
if bar is None:
  bar = no_bar(thing)
```

Comment: The reason for the error was what I wanted most, thank you.

I've found a simpler(?) method using or: `bar = thing.get("bar", False) or no_bar(thing)`
I understand None gets evaluated to False, but I just like making it explicit